# detect that page is a result of a refresh

Tags: javascript, dom

Hoping for some help trying to figure out how to detect that the current page was loaded as a result of a refresh.

In chrome, I can detect this with `document.referrer == document.location.href`.  (NOTE: I realize that this is not entirely reliable, but it is good enough for my purposes;  I don't care about bad behaviors here, just the positive path)

Unfortunately other Firefox (for example) still gives a document.referrer of '' after a refresh (assuming referrer was '' before refresh).

Does anyone know of a reasonable modern-browser-compatible way of detecting that the current page is the result of a refresh via javascript?

Comment: Use `localStorage` to store the location instead.

Comment: There's a history object you  could use (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). It's probably an array-like object, so you might want to make a proper array from it (like by pushing each of its element to a new array). Then you could check whether the current page matches the most recent page in the history.

Comment: Trying to watch refreshes smells like an antipattern. Keeping pages stateless is usually better practice and will reduce future headaches. Maybe you could share the higher motives so people can try and help find a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you refresh via javascript, set a timestamp or such in local storage. When the page loads, read the local storage;  If it is set and is close to the current timestamp, you have a refresh.